# How to parse JSON sections using json-simple in Java?

Tags: java, json, maven, json-simple

I'm currently using the Twitch API to get information about a livestream. However, I can't seem to get the data under the stream section for viewers and such. I'm using json-simple as a maven dependency.

```
{
  "_links": {
"channel": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/test_channel",
"self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/test_channel"},
"stream": {
"game": "StarCraft II: Heart of the Swarm",
"viewers": 2123,
"average_fps": 29.9880749574,
"delay": 0,
"video_height": 720,
"is_playlist": false,
"created_at": "2015-02-12T04:42:31Z",
"_id": 4989654544,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example for getting the `viewers` data:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
// handle exceptions for this line
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader(new File("data.json")));
JSONObject streamObject = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("stream");
long viewers = (Long) streamObject.get("viewers");
```